# Programmable universal remote

Tags: remote-control

I have a [NAD D 3020 amplifier](https://nadelectronics.com/product/d-3020-hybrid-digital-amplifier/) that comes with a remote controller, but the remote is crap (and I'm not the only one to say it). Fortunately, they have a document with all the [remote codes](https://nadelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/D-3020-Remote-Codes.pdf), some of which are not even available with the supplied remote. The codes are something like:

```
Function     Format Address Data   Address Data
                    Hex     Hex    Dec     Dec
-----------------------------------------------
Power Off    NEC    877C    C8     34684   200
...
```

Is there a universal remote that would allow programming its keys with these codes, instead of relying on manufacturer/model references (which may be wrong, or missing, or incomplete), or on learning (which requires a working remote to learn from)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is such a remote. There are probably quite a few of them but the one I tried is the [URC 6440](https://www.oneforall.com/urc6440-simple-4.html). With the help of the information in the http://www.hifi-remote.com/ (especially the [forums](http://www.hifi-remote.com/forums)), it's really easy to program with any OS: it mounts as a USB drive, and using [Remote Master](http://controlremote.sourceforge.net/Readme.html) it's just a matter of copying a file with the configuration. Specifically, [this](http://www.hifi-remote.com/forums/dload.php?action=file&file_id=25227) the configuration file I just created for the NAD D 3020 (without using the original remote at all), and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Logitech Harmony 785 - discontinued now - and it has the capability to learn controls from existing remotes. I'm not sure whether all the current crop all have the same capability, [but I would imagine so.](https://support.myharmony.com/en-gb/adding-a-device-thats-not-found-in-the-harmony-database)

https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/harmony-universal-remotes

Comment: Thanks, but I said "instead of relying on [...] learning (which requires a working remote to learn from)". The point is the current remote is so bad I can't count on it giving any reliable signal. It might work now, but who knows in a couple of years, when I may have to reprogram (for whatever reason) the universal remote? Also, there are some documented functions that are not available in the default remote, so I can't learn them from it.